# JSON UTF-8 encoding errors

Tags: java, json, character-encoding

I have some UTF8 encoding errors using JSON in JAVA:

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
json.put("Name", "Müller");
System.out.println(json.toString());
```

Output:

```
{"Name":"M\u00fcller"}
```

But I would like the following:

```
{"Name":"Müller"}
```

Any suggestions?
Stromsam

Comment: have you set the character-set ?

Comment: Which JSON library are you using?

Comment: how can I set the charset for a JSONObject?

Comment: This is not an error, it's a correct Unicode string escape. You're far more likely to get a real encoding error writing a Java String to a stream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few bits of info which will make this a more useful question.  firstly which JSON library are you using?  are you using this in a standalone app or as part of a Java web-app?

if you are using the org.json.JSONObject.JSONObject() then what you have written should work.

The library org.json is available here [json.org](http://json.org/java/)

running the below code with the suggested library :

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
json.put("Name", "Müller");
System.out.println(json.toString());
```

produces :

```
{"Name":"Müller"}
```

seems to be what you want

hope that helps

Olly

Comment: thanks a lot! I used json-rpc-1.0.jar. With the libary from json.org it works the way I wanted.